# What is the best way to change the font size and style of a lightning-card title?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

As the title says, what is the best way to change the font size and style of a lightning-card title. I have tried the following...

**1)** First, using these [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) on a lightning card...

```
:host {
    --slds-c-card-color-background: lightblue;
    --slds-c-card-heading-font-size: 2rem;
    --slds-c-card-sizing-border: 5px;
    --slds-c-card-heading-font-weight: 100;
}
```

All of them are applied except for `--slds-c-card-heading-font-size`, any ideas why? Additionally, there is no styling hook to change the header font.

**2)** I have found no other way to select the title of the lightning-card, and have tried many CSS selectors, including... `lightning-card`, `lightning-card[title]`, `.slds-card`, and `.slds-card__header-title`

**3)** From my understanding, using the [Base Card Structure](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#Base-Card-Structure) that starts with the HTML `<article class="slds-card">` instead of using `<lightning-card title="TitleToChangeFontOf">` would be equivalent, but I was hoping to avoid that because I imagine it would be harder to maintain, even though it might make it easier to select the title. Worst-case I could do this, but is there any downsides to be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is actually a `slot`, so you can force whatever styles you want directly into it.

```
<lightning-card>
  <h1 slot="title" style="font-size: 2em;">I am twice as large</h1>
</lightning-card>
```

This allows you to use most of the default card styles while being able to completely customize the slotted content.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/specification) suggests that you should use a `header` or `h1` tag, not an `article` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That worked. One follow up question, I'm slightly thrown off by the Base Card Structure in bullet 3 of my question. Is there ever a good reason to use that HTML structure over the <lightning-card> way?

Comment: @louis The reason for the blueprint is when you don't have the standard library available (e.g. you want to run a Heroku site that looks like SLDS).